# Call window.alert from nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

So I'm building a NodeJS web app, which involves saving data via Mongoose as shown below.

I need to show a popup window when the saving is done.

```
// Update the user model
    User.updateOne({userId: request.user.userId}, {$push: {saved: [parseInt(request.query.saveId)]}}, function(error, success){
            if(error){
                console.log(error)
            } else {
             // 
             // Show a window alert in javascript here

            }
    });
```

Though I'm aware that NodeJS and JS have completely different functions, is there any way I can call window.alert via NodeJS, by some type of URL perhaps?

Comment: Please do tell if you are using a view engine or serving HTML pages directly?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ejs. However, I don't want the page to refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ejs file add a script tag like this

```
<script>
    fetch('/users/update', { method:'POST',data: JSON.stringify(user)  }})
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then(data => window.alert(data))
         .catch(err => window.alert("Error updating user:" + err.message))
</script>
```

Within `JSON.stringify(user)`, `user` object is should be obtained from render

And create a route that would match `/users/update` and have DB things done here

```
app.post('/users/update',(req,res) => {
    User.updateOne({userId: req.user.userId}, {$push: {saved: [parseInt(request.query.saveId)]}}, function(error, success){
            if(error){
                 res.status(500).json({message: erroe.message})
            } else {
                 res.json({message: "User updated"})
            }
    });
})
```